# R - Loading dplyr issue

Tags: r, dplyr

I am New to R and stackoverflow. The problem I am facing is that when I try to load `dplyr` from packages it gives me below error

```r
library(dplyr)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
 unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/mhashim/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/rlang/libs/x64/rlang.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  Access is denied.
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘dplyr’ was built under R version 3.4.4
```

I have tried changing the library path 
`.libPaths( c( .libPaths(), "C:/new_software/Rpackages") )` but doesn't help.

Comment: Can you give a few more details about your setup? This looks like a permission problem.

Comment: yes it certainly is a permission issue. I know a path that wont have a permission issue hence i need to change the path of the libraries. Or the default path where the loading happens

Comment: What happens if you install the package, copy the packages to the approved path and change them with .libPaths?